# Sql join problem that I can't connect to the insert

Tags: postgresql, join

- `para` table is composed of: `domain, code, description`
- `work_operation` table is composed of: `work_operation_id, description`
- `oper_work_dpi` table is composed of `work_operation_id,ork_id_operation_id, dpi_code`
- `myDpi` table   consists of: `operation_id, id_dpi`

when i try to insert to populate i can't connect

```
insert into oper_work_dpi (dpi_code) (
select a.work_operation_id from work_operation as a
join myDpi  as dpi on a.work_operation_id = dpi.operation_id 
join para as pa on pa.code= dpi.id_dpi
);
```

what did i do wrong?

Comment: Please detail error message if you have one otherwise give input data and expected output data.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why. PS Explain "i can't connect".

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no log, I will guess that "as" is wrong, remove it. Something like:

```
insert into oper_work_dpi (dpi_code)
select a.work_operation_id from work_operation a
join myDpi dpi on a.work_operation_id = dpi.operation_id 
join para pa on pa.code= dpi.id_dpi;
```